# Renaming parent directory of a directory that has symbolic links pointed to

Tags: symlink

I have created `x` number of symbolic links (`ln -s path file`) to a directory named `templates` that lives within `mytheme` directory. I would like to rename the theme folder but don't know the consequence of this with the symbolic links I've created previously. I have roughly about 50. What would happen to them? Do they just die and would need re-doing one by one or is there a quick way? Here is the structure:

```
themes
  mytheme
    templates
      ...
  _theme-x1
    templates //symbolic link
  _theme-x2
    templates //symbolic link
  ....
  _theme-x50
    templates //symbolic link
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to redo all the links...

If the `templates` is common to all maybe you should put it in a `themes/common` directory and have all the themes link to it.

```
 for theme in *; do cd "$theme" ; rm templates ; ln -s ../common/templates . ; cd - ; done
```